# UISearchBar fetching data from Json

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am using api. I post some data and store response in tableview. I put searchbar for search data from  tableview. I want when I write 3 words in searchbar after that my api will call and data show in the tableview. I am using uitextfield for searchbar.

```
var array = [String]()
var tabledata = [String]()
var tableFilterData = [String]()
var isSearch :Bool!

let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"

@IBOutlet weak var searchTextfield: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBAction func textfieldchanged(_ sender: Any) {

      tableview.isHidden = true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    isSearch = false
    self.apicalling()

    searchTextfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldActive), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)

}
  public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{

    var searchText  = textField.text! + string

    if string  == "" {
        searchText = (searchText as String).substring(to: searchText.index(before: searchText.endIndex))
    }
    if searchText == "" {
        isSearch = false
        tableview.reloadData()
    }
    else{
        getSearchArrayContains(searchText)
    }

    return true
}
 func getSearchArrayContains(_ text : String) {
    var predicate : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", text)
     tableFilterData = (tabledata as NSArray).filtered(using: predicate) as! [String]
    isSearch = true
    tableview.reloadData()

}
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{  
    heightConstraint.constant = tableview.contentSize.height
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    guard let touch:UITouch = touches.first else
    {
        return;
    }
    if touch.view != tableview
    {
        searchTextfield.endEditing(true)
        tableview.isHidden = true
    }
}

@objc func textFieldActive() {

     tableview.isHidden = !tableview.isHidden
}
 func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
```

my tableview part is this

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isSearch! {
        return tableFilterData.count
    }
    else{
        return tabledata.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as UITableViewCell!
    // Set text from the data model

    if isSearch! {
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableFilterData[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.font = searchTextfield.font
    }
    else{
        cell.textLabel?.text = tabledata[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.font = searchTextfield.font
    }
    return cell
}
```

In my api calling my parameter is this

```
  let param = ["var_name": "sha","API":"user_search","auth_token":authToken!]
```

but I want searchdata pass into the "var_name" .
my searchbar is working properly but I want when I write 3 words in searchbar after that api will call and that three data pass into the api as a parameters in "var_name".

Comment: Unrelated but why is `isSearch` optional? Declare the property `var isSearch = false` and remove `isSearch = false` in `viewDidLoad` and all related exclamation marks.

Comment: If you want to call api when user entered 3 character then you need to check text count like this `if searchText.count >= 3` then do further execution.

Comment: but in which function?  in this func shouldChangeCharactersIn range ?

Comment: iOS provides `UISearchController` and `UISearchBar` for these reasons